# How to see "order-book" of a liquidity pool?

Tags: horizon, offer

I've been watching trading activity on yETH/XLM market today and realized that while the orderbook API (i.e. stream from `horizon.stellar.org/order_book`) keeps returning order-books with very wide spread (e.g. lowest ask=12500; highest bid=5000), there are frequent trades with price somewhere in between. The trades have `base_` or `counter_liquidity_pool_id` filled, so obviously executed against a liquidity pool.
I feel that the orderbook API doesn't give me full information anymore as it doesn't include all the liquidity available, including AMM. Is there a way to get the information?